# Get event when scrollviewer ended WinUI3 WinAppSDK

Tags: c#, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

I'm using ScrollViewers inside NavigationViewItems, and I need choose next item after ending of scrollview automatically. I tried to find scroll ending event in docs, but I doesn't find it. Can you help me with it? How I can catch ScrollViewer ending for item changing?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a simple navigation.

```xml
<NavigationView>
    <NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <NavigationViewItem
            Content="A"
            Tag="PageA" />
        <NavigationViewItem
            Content="B"
            Tag="PageB" />
    </NavigationView.MenuItems>
    <ScrollViewer
        x:Name="ContentScrollViewer"
        ViewChanged="ScrollViewer_ViewChanged">
        <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" />
    </ScrollViewer>
</NavigationView>
```

Then you can use the `ViewChangedEvent` like this.

```cs
private void ScrollViewer_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is ScrollViewer scrollViewer)
    {
        if (this.ContentFrame.Content is PageA &&
            scrollViewer.VerticalOffset == scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight)
        {
            // Navigate to Page B
        }
        else if (this.ContentFrame.Content is PageB &&
            scrollViewer.VerticalOffset == 0)
        {
            // Navigate to Page A
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed to enable my "Next" button when a EULA was scrolled to the bottom in WinUI 3, thank you.